# Кодировка комментариев в всплывающих подсказках Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Работаю в Visual Studio 2013, все файлы в юникоде. При наведении на переменную или функцию выходит подсказка с описанием, включая комментарий. Комментарии написаны на русском (переписывать все на английском не вариант, т.к. я делаю только часть проекта и код не мой по большей части), но при наведении вместо нормального комментария идут кракозябры

[image]

При этом если параллельно открыть файл в соседней вкладке, содержащий объявление с этим злосчастным комментарием, то комментарий покажется нормально.

[image]

Но если у меня проект с 40 файлами, все их держать открытыми как-то не очень. Есть нормальное решение проблемы?

Comment: Сохраните все файлы как Unicode, а не в cp1251?

Comment: @VladD все исходники набраны в юникоде